# Generating SWIG bindings with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, swig, introspection

How would I generate automatic bindings for a C project that is built using CMake?

I want to generate bindings for Python, Java, .NET, PHP, Perl, TCL, Ruby and Octave automatically.

Comment: This SO question is somewhat related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515374/using-swig-with-a-build-system

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find an example [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Introduction.html#Introduction_build_system).

Snippet:

> The following example is a CMake input file for creating a python wrapper for the SWIG interface file, example.i:
>
> ```
> # This is a CMake example for Python
>
> FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
> INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
>
> FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
>
> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
>
> SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")
>
> SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
> SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
> SWIG_ADD_MODULE(example python example.i example.cxx)
> SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
> ```

Comment: Beginning [with CMake 3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/UseSWIG.html) it's SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY rather than SWIG_ADD_MODULE. The CMake documentation is probably better than the SWIG documentation.