# Using SWIG with a build system

Tags: interface-builder, build-automation, cmake, swig

Anyone have experience with using SWIG (the interface generator)?

I have a C project which I would like to expose to a bunch of other languages/frameworks, like Python, Java, .NET, Perl, PHP, Ruby.

I would like to integrate with my build system (which is CMake-based), but any method of accomplishing this will do.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake comes with a module for building SWIG wrappers.

Your CMakeLists.txt should include something like this:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SWIG_ADD_MODULE(example python example.i example.cxx)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

See http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_CMake_to_generate_SWIG_wrapper_libraries.3F for more details (the above example is taken from there...)