# Adding Lua scripting to a hobby ray tracer

Tags: lua, cmake, swig

Taking my hobby ray tracer to the next level, I decided to replace my custom configuration file, where I store mesh file names and things like light location and materials, with Lua script.

This would make my configuration more flexible and, I hope, to add things like generation of video with animation, not just dummy images from fixed position eye.

I see it with SWIG which will generate some c++ file out of my raytracer.i. Ideally, I would want to change my cmake file, so that all the magic happens in it. My main function would look like

```
int main(...) {
    return run_lua_script(argv[1]);
}
```

During build process SWIG, somehow, would step in, and generate this cpp file and then cmake would add this file to the list of cpp files of my executable.

Does this make scene? If so, are there examples of such CMakeLists.txt?

(please note that I want to generate executable which will open lua file, but not a *.so or *.dll to load from lua script).

Comment: What about the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Introduction.html#Introduction_build_system)? That's the third result of googling "SWIG CMake", first two being the actual CMake documentation, and 4th being [an answered SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1670197/3962537).

Comment: Apologies I did not make it clear, but I need to build executable, not *.so (or dll).

Comment: @asyrov: "*I need to build executable, not *.so (or dll).*" A trivial distinction, one that has nothing to do with SWIG itself. Also, it's not clear why you are against using a DLL, since your final EXE will be functionally no different from having `lua.exe` load your DLL.

Comment: Just in case you're not happy with the SWIG support CMake ships with, you can always implement it yourself -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26211863/3962537).

Comment: I will use Lua for a minor task, but mostly will develop in qt with c++. Lua script is just a 50 line configuration. My plan is to have 'main' function as I outlined above. I already did something like it with lualite library, but like idea of SWIG better (more automatic with more languages). You pointed me to a good question, but maybe someone could answer it exact, to save my time for ray tracer itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @asyrov If it's as simple as you described it, it's basically the first three commands in that answer I linked. You just need to figure out the command you need to invoke SWIG to process your interface file on command line. 5 minute job, 10 if you really take your time grokking the documentation of those 3 commands.